# Drag lock doesn't get disabled

Tags: macos, trackpad, accessibility

I've enabled dragging in the touchpad settings in Accessibility, but I've also chosen "without drag lock". However, the dragging still continues after I lift my finger, just as it does when I choose "with drag lock". Is this a known problem in Yosemite?

Comment: Happens to me too.

Comment: Still present in 2023, good job!